# How can I write data from txt file to database?

Tags: c++, database, file, postgresql, text-files

If I have a txt with a certain number of rows and column (number of columns unknown at the beginning, columns are separated by tab), how can I export the data into the database? I have managed to iterate through the first row to count the number of columns and create a table accordingly but now I need to go through each row and insert the data into the respective column. How can I do that?

Example of the txt file:

```
Name Size Population GDP
aa 2344 1234 12
bb 2121 3232 15
... ... .. .. 
.. .. .. ..
```

The table has been created:

```
CREATE TABLE random id INT, Name char(20), Size INT, Population INT, GDP INT
```

Answer (score 1):

The difficult part is reading in the text fields.  According to your definition, the field titles are separated by spaces.  Is this true for the text fields?

A generic process is:

```
Create an SQL CREATE statement from the header text.
Execute the SQL statement.
While reading a line of text doesn't fail do
    Parse the text into variables.
    Create an SQL INSERT statement using field names and values from the variables.
    Execute the SQL statement.
End-While
```

Another solution is to convert the TXT file into tab or comma separated fields.  Check your database documentation to see if there is a function for *loading files* and also discover the characters used for separating columns.

If you need specific help, please ask a more specific or detailed question.

Comment: Sorry, yeah the TXT file is tab-delimited. I am using C++, so I read the file using ifstream, created a table "random" with one column "id" (it should contain the unique id of the txt file, I want to store more than one txt file in the same table), then I went through the first line using isstringstream and used ALTER TABLE random ADD ...) to add the required number of columns. What should I do enter the data from the file + id (assigned by the user) into the table "random"?

Comment: You can store multiple files in the same table *as long as the files have the same field names and types*.  As far as the user ID goes, that information would be best in another table.  Perhaps a table of [user id, filename, table name].  Search the web for "database normal form".  You want to set up the databases to reduce data duplication across tables.

Answer (score 1):

something like this might work.
basic idea is to use print statements to transform the line into SQL commannds.
then you can execute these commands using a sql command interpreter.

```
cat textfile.txt | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) /'\1' /; s/[ \t]+/,/g;' | awk '($NR!=1) {print "INSERT INTO random (Name,size,population,gdp) VALUES (" $0 ");" }' > sqlcommands.txt
```

for the unknown number of columns, this might work.

```
cat textfile.txt | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) /'\1' /; s/[ \t]+/,/g;' | awk '($NR!=1) {print "INSERT INTO random VALUES (ID," $0 ");" }' > sqlcommands.txt
```

replace ID with the id value needed. but you will need to execute it separately for each ID value.

Comment: In this case, I should know the exact number of columns but when I first start, I wouldn't know how many columns are there. So, would INSERT INTO random (Name,size,population,gdp) work for all cases? I mean I could have something like Name size population gdp whatever whatever2 as well, I wouldn't know the number of columns nor their names to start with. :S

Comment: @kenny: yeah, saw the c++ only after your comment.  but hope this is still useable.

Comment: And I don't know how to use this in C++. :(

Comment: system("cat textfile ................... >sqlcommands.txt");
  
--- ;) 
jokes aside, neither i know how to do this easily in c++

Answer (score 1):

Using PostgreSQL's [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-copy.html), command, something like:

```
COPY random FROM 'filename' WITH DELIMITER '\t'
```

Answer (score 0):

I work with Sybase where "bcp" utility does this. Quick google on "postgres bcp" brings up this:

http://lists.plug.phoenix.az.us/pipermail/plug-devel/2000-October/000103.html

I realize its not the best answer, but good enough to get you going, I hope.

Oh, and you may need to change your text format, make it comma or tab-delimited. Use sed for that.

Comment: I looked at "Adding Data with COPY" but I could only find instruction on how to add data to a table given a filename. What if I had to read in the filename (using ifstream)? Also, I need to add unique id along with the rest of the data from the file.

Comment: Ah, then you're asking how to add rows to database when the values are already in the C program memory? In that case you need to clarify your question.